# Data not rendering in salesforce UI LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, template

I am new to LWC  i have created a simple quiz app  but the data is being not rendered in the salesforce UI . I  have checked the code correctly but could see still the data  is not being rendered in the UI

Html File :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Quiz App In LWC">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={myQuestions} for:item="quiz">
                    <div key={quiz.id}  class="slds-m-bottom_medium">
                        <div><strong>{quiz.id} - {quiz.question}</strong></div>     
                    </div>           
                </template>
                </div>
         </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Js file :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class QuizApp extends LightningElement {
    myQuestions = [

        {

            id:"question1",
            question: "Which one of the following is not a template loop?",
            answers:{
                a:"for:each",
                b:"iterator",
                c:"map loop"

            },
            correctanswer:"c"
        },
        {
            id:"Question2",
            question:"Which of the file is invald in LWC component folder?",
            answers:{
                a:".svg",
                b:".apex",
                c:".js"
            },
            correctAnswer:"b"
        },
        {
            id:"Question3",
            question:"WHich one of the following is not a directive?",
            answers:{
                a:"for:each",
                b:"if:true",
                c:"@track"
            },
            correctAnswer:"c"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Salesforce UI image]

Comment: There is no issue with this code it seems. It renders just fine. https://webcomponents.dev/edit/j7HNcKqu73PLH02PS7gr. If the `myQuestions` variable is supplied with data later, you may want to add `track` but this code works just fine.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine now earlier i have only deployed the HTML file so i was facing the issue